# javascript getElementById on span

Tags: javascript, html

I have a row of results: name, amount and I want to add a X at the end of the row allowing deletion of the entire row.

I gave only one row here, for brievity. There are many and I though of putting this in a `for`.

This is my html :

```js
let lignesRecurrentes = document.getElementsByClassName('ligne_recurrente')

for (var i = 0; i < lignesRecurrentes.length; i++) {
    let ligneRecurrente = lignesRecurrentes[i]
    let id = ligneRecurrente.id.replace('ligne_','')
    let croix = document.getElementById('suppr_recurrente_'+id)

    croix.addEventListener('click', function(){
  console.log(croix.innerHTML)
  }
  )}
```

```html
        <div class="ligne_recurrente" id="ligne_3">
            <span class="intitule" id="intitulerec_3">Cousteau</span>
            <span class="montant">
                <span class="chiffre_recur" id="montant_3">396,00</span>
                <span class="euro">&#8364;</span>
                <span id="suppr_recurrente_3 " >&nbsp;X</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="smalrec_3"></div>
```

How come `croix` is null? Can't add eventListerner on null?

Comment: First, when are you trying to run that JavaScript? It must be after the HTML has been created and parsed into memory. Second, [don't use `getElementsByClassName()` (especially for looping purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474).

Comment: Typo: The `id` attribute has whitespace at the end. This would have been picked up if you had [validated](https://validator.nu/)

Comment: And, you really don't need `id`s or that loop in the first place. All you need to do is have a `click` event handler on the `span` that does this one line: `this.closest(".ligne_recurrente").remove();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by trailing space in `id="suppr_recurrente_3 "`

BTW, You can simplyfiy your js with wrapping rows into some div

```
        <div class="rows">
          <div class="ligne_recurrente" id="ligne_3">
              <span class="intitule" id="intitulerec_3">Cousteau</span>
              <span class="montant">
                  <span class="chiffre_recur" id="montant_3">396,00</span>
                  <span class="euro">&#8364;</span>
                  <span class="btn-remove">&nbsp;X</span>
              </span>
          </div>
          <div id="smalrec_3"></div>
        </div>
```

attach listener do this container and check if clicked element has desired class:

```
document.querySelector('.rows').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target, id;

    if (target.classList.contains('btn-remove')) {
        id = target.parentElement.parentElement.id.replace('ligne_', '');

        console.log('line ' + id + ' should be removed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply your code combing:

- [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)
- [.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

In order to remove the entire row it's enough to use [.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) in the event handler.

The snippet:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.ligne_recurrente span span:last-child').forEach(function(ele) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        this.closest('div.ligne_recurrente').remove();
    });
})
```

```html
<div class="ligne_recurrente" id="ligne_3">
    <span class="intitule" id="intitulerec_3">Cousteau</span>
            <span class="montant">
                <span class="chiffre_recur" id="montant_3">396,00</span>
                <span class="euro">&#8364;</span>
                <span id="suppr_recurrente_3" >&nbsp;X</span>
            </span>
</div>
<div id="smalrec_3"></div>
```